# Saving base64 encoded string video to disk

Tags: video, go, base64

In order to save videos uploaded through json, I came up with this function:

```
func SaveBase64VidToDisk(vidString string) (interface{}, error) {
    vidExt := strings.ToLower(strings.Split(strings.Split(vidString, ";")[0], "/")[1])
    vidData := strings.Split(vidString, ";base64,")[1]
    vidReader := base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(vidData))
    fmt.Println("vidEXT is:", videExt)

    dir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    destDir := "/media/videos/"
    path := dir + destDir
    vidFileName := getRandomFileName("randomstr") + "." + vidExt
    vidFile, err := os.Create(path + vidFileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }

    defer vidFile.Close()

    if _, err := vidFile.Write(vidData); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error saving video")
        panic(err)
        return nil, nil
    }
    return vidFileName, nil

}

func getRandomFileName(prefix string) string {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    l := len(prefix)
    result := make([]byte, l)
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        result[i] = CHARS[rand.Intn(len(CHARS))]
    }
    return string(result)
}
```

However this gives the error:

```
shared/saveimage.go:117: cannot use vidData (type string) as type []byte in argument to vidFile.Write
```

admittedly I don't know what decoder should I use to save the data so `SaveBase64VidToDisk` is a shut in the dark, so appreciate your help to fix this.

Comment: why do you use `interface{}` type if you're just returning a string?

Comment: @srxf because if I use string as return type, I get `cannot use nil as type string in return argument`. But that is not really the issue here.

Comment: yes you're right, but it can be improved by using just string, and instead of returning `nil`, you can just return empty string. just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work as `vidData` is a string containing the base64 encoded video. What you want is to read the data from `vidReader`, and save that. It's an io.Reader so you can use the Read function to read data from it.

Alternatively, use the [Decode String](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#example_Encoding_DecodeString) function in the base64 package to read it straight into a `[]byte`.

```
data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(vidData)
vidFile.Write(data)
```

Comment: Kindly, accompany answer with code, and I'll accept it: `data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(vidData) vidFile.Write(data)`

Comment: Code example added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just do

```
vidFile.Write([]byte(vidData))
```

Edit: Oh, I see, I thought you literally wanted to save the video base64encoded.  Sounds like you want to do:

```
data := []byte{}
base64.StdEncoding.Decode(data, vidData)
vidFile.Write(data)
```

Comment: Well, this removes error and saves a file. But the file can not be played as .mp4 video.

Comment: Now I get `cannot use data (type int) as type []byte in argument to vidFile.Write
`

Comment: sorry, didn't realize decode returns the length, see edit